# Calling POST operation of REST API in node Js GET call

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I am executing a POST operation over a REST API which returns JSON data. I'm trying to make that call with Node JS and I'm not getting any response . Could some one help me finding what is the issue here?

```
'use strict';

const request = require('request');

const snapOpts = {
    url: 'https://triageqa.paypalcorp.com:8443/v1/triage/fetchers',
    method: 'POST',
    strictSSL: false
};

const snapFilter = {
    "reporter": "sdmariappan",
    "fetchers_list": {
        "change_ticket_fetcher_request" :         {
            "start_time": "2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "end_time": "2018-02-07T00:00:00.000Z",
            "pools" : [
                "xxx"
            ]
        }

    }
};

let obj;

module.exports = function (router) {
    router.get('/snap', function (req, res) {
        callsnap(function (data) {
            res.send(data)
        });
    });
};

function callsnap(cb) {
    requestSnap("POST", snapFilter)
        .then(data => {
            obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data,null,2));
            cb(obj);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        });
}

function requestSnap(method, queryData) {
    snapOpts.method = method;
    snapOpts.qs = queryData;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let responseData = '';
        request(snapOpts)
            .on('error', err => reject(err))
            .on('data', chunk => responseData += chunk)
            .on('end', () => resolve(responseData));
    });
}
```

Curl command to call the REST API:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer EEwJ6tF9x5' -d ' {
    "reporter": "sdmariappan",
    "fetchers_list": {
         "change_ticket_fetcher_request" :         {
             "start_time": "2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "end_time": "2018-02-07T00:00:00.000Z",
            "pools" : [ 
                "xxx", 
            ]
         }

   }
}
} ' 'https://triageqa.paypalcorp.com:8443/v1/triage/fetchers'
```

Comment: in post-operation you have to pass body not **qs**

Comment: .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        }); you are just printing error not returning response you should return response.

Comment: I have a callback(cb(obj)) which returns the response. 
any sample for passing the body? I'm just setting the query parameters.

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot Rahul.

After adding the content-type in header, I could see the response. It was my mistake for not seeing tat properly:(

```
const snapOpts = {
    url: 'https://triageqa.paypalcorp.com:8443/v1/triage/fetchers',
    method: 'POST',
    json: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I have done some modification.

```
module.exports = function (router) {
    router.get('/snap', function (req, res) {
        requestSnap("POST", snapFilter)
            .then(data => {
                res.json(data);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.status(400).json(data);
            });
    });
};

function requestSnap(method, queryData) {
    snapOpts.method = method;
    snapOpts.body = queryData;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(snapOpts, function (err, res, body) {
            if (err) {
                console.error('error posting json: ', err)
                reject(err);
            }
            console.log('body: ', body);
            resolve(body);
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But still I'm getting error as 'error posting json:  Error: Argument error, options.body.' . sorry. i'm new to Node JS

Comment: try  snapOpts.formData instead of  snapOpts.body

Comment: This error now :   (node:108568) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): ReferenceError: data is not defined
(node:108568) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: use form instead of the body.

Comment: That gives the 200 response  :) But the body is empty .. console.log('body: ', body); I'm expecting something like {  "triage_id": 11111 }

Comment: I'm not getting what's error in that. this should work.

Comment: yes. i did. response is something like  { "triage_id": 11111 }

Comment: do one thing go to the postman, get the node.js code from there and try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165202/discussion-between-msd-and-rahul-sharma).